# Simplexml Add Attribute with many parameter

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I try to create following xml line with simple xml and php:

```
  <stream languageCode="BG" mpegStreamID="0xBD" mpegSubstreamID="0x20"/>
  <stream languageCode="EN" mpegStreamID="0xBD" mpegSubstreamID="0x21"/>
  <stream languageCode="FR" mpegStreamID="0xBD" mpegSubstreamID="0x22"/>
```

so far I did this in a loop:

```
foreach($langs as $key => $value)
{
    $this->lang->addAttribute('languageCode', $var1, 'mpegStreamID', '0xBD', 'mpegSubStreamID', '0x2'.$i);
}
```

but I get following error:

> SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute() expects at most 3 parameters, 6 given

Thus I tried this:

```
    foreach($langs as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->streamLang->addAttribute('languageCode', $var);
        $this->streamLang->addAttribute('mpegStreamID', '0xBD');
        $this->streamLang->addAttribute('mpegSubStreamID', '0x2'.$i);
        $i++;
    }
```

But get this error:

> add Attribute does already exist

The Errors are fairly clear, but I do not know how to create a workaround so to say.

Comment: So what's the problem, the error is fairly clear. Wants at most 3, you've provided 6. http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php

Comment: @justbaron The question is fairly clear. There has to be a way to make the xml look like the lines above

Comment: the first error is pretty clear. The second error probably relates to your foreach loop. It lists $langs, $keys and $values, none of which are used in addAttribute, which means that you are attempting to add the attribute to a single SimpleXML object, multiple times.

Comment: Correct, but I do not know how to make it work right now

Comment: You want to add 3 different attributes to a single XML node, so remove the foreach loop, it's pointless.

Comment: In both your loops, you do not use *$key* or *$value*, so you repeat actions for each loop iteration.

Comment: The given code is still not a [mcve], because we don't know what `$langs` is, and the variables `$var` and `$i` are not defined anywhere either. We shouldn't need to guess which of these mistakes is your actual problem, and which is just the sample code you've given.

Comment: @justbaron I *think* the foreach loop is intended to add a new element each time, but either that code has been left out of the example, or that's where the code is going wrong. The code given is so incomplete it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: @IMSop Agreed, I think that's the intention, however in this question and the problems/errors being described....the foreach loops and variables are pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message is self explaining, here some functions that allow you to use a variable count of arguments, but most are not. `SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute()` expects name, value and optionally a namespace. You have to call it for each attribute you would like to add.

In the loop you add the 3 attributes to the same node several times. So in the second iteration the attribute does already exists and the call fails.

Here not enough of you source (obviously it is part of a larger class - you use $this) to say a lot more about it. But here is an complete example:

```
$languages = ['BG', "EN", "FR"];

$streams = new SimpleXMLElement('<streams/>');
foreach ($languages as $index => $language) {
  $stream = $streams->addChild('stream');
  $stream->addAttribute('languageCode', $language);
  $stream->addAttribute('mpegStreamID', '0xBD');
  $stream->addAttribute('mpegSubStreamID', '0x2'.($index + 1));
}

echo $streams->asXml();
```

This will look nearly the same if you're using DOM:

```
$languages = ['BG', "EN", "FR"];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$streams = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('streams'));
foreach ($languages as $index => $language) {
  $stream = $streams->appendChild($document->createElement('stream'));
  $stream->setAttribute('languageCode', $language);
  $stream->setAttribute('mpegStreamID', '0xBD');
  $stream->setAttribute('mpegSubStreamID', '0x2'.($index + 1));
}
$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXml();
```